# Grunt not working in IIS application

Tags: gruntjs

I am running an ASP. NET application and calling a batch file using Process.Start(). The file contains some grunt commands. On opening the file using Start.Process() I get an error saying  "'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n".  I have added nodejs and npm to the environment variable PATH. The same code works fine on Production server.

Comment: Did you install grunt using npm?

Comment: Yes I have installed grunt using command npm install -g grunt-cli

Answer (score 0):

maybe that link can help you?

https://github.com/kanema/grunt-iis